# Write console output to a file

Tags: linux, console, console-application

I want to collect and write the CONSOLE output to a file. 
Actually, the output need to be displayed on CONSOLE as well.
I tried below code just to get each line buffer of CONSOLE but it's not correct:

```
        while(!feof(stdout))
        {
            fgets(szReadBuff, sizeof(szReadBuff), stdout);
            // Then write szReadBuff to a created file
            ...
        }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `but it's correct` - so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to run `./myprogram | tee output.txt` from your shell. `tee` is a utility that allows you to write to both standard output and one or more files.